# Can MBP 13 mid 2012 send audio and video through thunderbolt to HDMI?

Tags: audio, thunderbolt, hdmi

I own this model: https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649?locale=en_US

And I have an adapter thunderbolt to HDMI that works wonderfully with video, but no audio.

Does someone has any advice on a product or the info about the capabilites of my mac to send audio AND video through thunderbolt port?

Comment: What adapter are you using?  Can you provide a link to exactly which one you purchased?  I suspect the problem is your adapter doesn't support audio even though your computer does.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, thunderbolt to HDMI by default provides audio.  Now, whether your adapter supports it, well that's another question.

I have used [this device](http://amzn.to/1XP4FS2) from Amazon Basics to supply HDMI to a TV (including audio) from a MBP and a Microsoft Surface Pro 3.  It worked with zero issues.

Answer (score 0):

We've switched from HDMI cables and dongles to Cable Matters HDMI <> Mini DisplayPort cables, as [found on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CADY9I). They come in different lengths and colors.

In actuality, you are not connecting with Thunderbolt - the Thunderbolt port is used as a Mini DisplayPort connector.